# How to make a regression model that never underestimates?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, overfitting-underfitting

I want to predict emergency resources that can be overestimated but should not be underestimated. Is there any loss function or penalties for underestimation or bias correction methods? Please provide examples, if available.

I want to use any ML (ANN or Decision Trees etc.) regression model to predict resources that avoids underestimation.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of how you ask it: that is impossible. There will never be a model that can *guarantee* no underestimation. Even an `outputA x 10` will not solve the problem, since a/ `outputA` may be too small, or b/ the `demandA` is even much higher.

On the other hand, models can be extremely good nowadays in making good predictions. So if you combine this with another system for checking, or manual checks, or an emergency system to deliver in case of failures, this will be very solid.

Mathematically, while on the inputs you can add any kind of restriction and bias -- on the output you can do only very simple things. For example, you could add a `min(outputA, minA)` but this is not very smart. Still, maybe your best shot...

... so not a very satisfying answer but I fear there is no silver bullet here.